# Can't write file on SD-card (Is a directory)

Tags: android, file, sd-card, writer

I'm getting the following error when trying to write midi-file on the Android SD-Card:

```
12-14 16:22:22.219: ERROR/Thread writer(1108): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/folder/midifiles/file.mid (Is a directory) in /mnt/sdcard/folder/midifiles/
```

That's the relevant code:

```
public void writeFile(String filename, String dir, int bpm) throws Exception {          

    File f = new File(dir,filename);    
    if(!f.exists()) {
        f.mkdirs();

        if(!f.createNewFile()) {
            return; 
        }
    }
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
```

I'm receiving the path via

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

The relevant permission has been included as well.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The file-writer is located in an external project/library... if this is in any case useful to know.

I guess that this is kind of a simple mistake, but I honestly have no idea what went wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a folder file.mid in the directory /mnt/sdcard/folder/midifiles/ on your sd card?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the directory `/mnt/sdcard/folder/midifiles/file.mid` with

```
f.mkdirs();
```

You should just do:

```
File f = new File(dir);    
if(!f.exists()) {
    f.mkdirs();

    File f1 = new File(dir,filename);    
    if(!f1.createNewFile()) {
       return; 
    }
}
```

or just

```
File f = new File(dir,filename);    
if(!f.exist()) {
    f.createNewFile();
    return; 
}
```

Comment: This didn't work out for me. The bloody thing simply doesn't recognize that the path given includes the file's name, but it creates a folder within the correct path with the file-name as folder-name on the device.

Comment: Sorry don't follow, are you trying to create the directories separate or just run `createNewFile`?

Comment: Update your question with the code you are trying now and I am sure we can work it out

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this on your phone? or connected to your pc? because it may be looking on your pc.